# NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined

Tags: python, setuptools

I have viewed several other posts and tried `--upgrade` to upgrade `setuptools`, but not helps.

The output as follows, by the way I use OSX,

My python version is `Python 2.7.6 --  64-bit`

```
   ~$ pip install urlopen

Collecting urlopen
  Using cached urlopen-1.0.0.zip
    .....
        return eval(compiled_marker, environment)

      File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>

    NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/tb/gh49g76s63l3rk1p63lfbs800000gn/T/pip-build-navlZP/urlopen
```

---

UPDATE:

I try to uninstall 'distribute' first, but it fails what does the output mean

```
~$ pip uninstall distribute
You are using pip version 6.0.6, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Not uninstalling distribute at /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages, outside environment /Users/lilisun/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User
```

---

update: 2016-08-19

This problem is solved by using `enpkg setuptools` and `enpkg pip`. I GUESS the problem may be caused by sth. related to virtual environment of Canopy.

Comment: I'm cofused? Are you trying to install urlopen? Urlopen is part of the urllib package which is included with Python.

Comment: @Harrison, nope i upgrade the setuptools

Comment: Have you tried `pip uninstall distribute` prior to upgrading?

Comment: @Harrison, check my updates

Comment: `pip install --upgrade distribute` Let me know if that has any effect.

Comment: @Harrison, the command fails with error  `NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined`